# c++ process finished with exit code

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and working on a function that first prompts the user to enter number of chair, surface area, color of the chair and then prompts the user to enter the type of wood - m for mahogany, o for oak, or p for pine and ideally any other entry should be rejected.
After entering the chair color I'm getting "Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)" instead of prompting the user to select woodtype.

```
}
```

}
lab1.h

```
#ifndef LAB1_H
#define LAB1_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int takeNumOfChair(int numOfChair);
float takeSurfaceArea(float surfaceArea);
string takeColourOfSeats(string colourOfSeats);
void takeTypeOfWood(char typeOfWood);
```

Comment: Why did you empty your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program invokes *undefined behavior* by falling at end of non-void functions without executing `return` statement.

You have to add `return` statements or change the return types of functions to `void`.

Your return type of the function `takeTypeOfWood` is already `void`, so it seems you should use `void` for the return types of the other functions in `lab1.h` and `lab1.cpp`.